# Temporarily show the documentation for a emacs lisp function

Tags: help, documentation

I want to bind a key which when pressed shows the documentation for an emacs lisp function, but as non-disruptive as possible. I want the contents of `describe-function` but jumping directly to the docs for the symbol I'm at if there is an exact match and shown in a temporary popup, perhaps at the bottom of the screen, that goes away if any key is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user thblt@irc.freenode.net#emacs provided the following implementation of a function that shows the documentation in the echo area at the bottom of emacs:

```el
(defun showdoc (f)
  (interactive (list (thing-at-point 'symbol t)))
    (message "%s: %s" f (documentation (intern f))))
```

I noticed that if the docstring was long, as for example with interactive, only the bottom part would be show; but it is often the top that is the most interesting. So I expanded on the function so that it would show the function signature at the top, and only show as many lines that fit in the echo area.

```el
(defun elisp-showdoc (f)
  (interactive (list (thing-at-point 'symbol t)))
  (message
   "%s"
   (let* ((doc-list      (split-string (documentation (intern f)) "\n"))
          (number-lines  (min (- (floor (* max-mini-window-height (frame-height))) 2)
                              (- (length doc-list) 2)))
          (subset        (concatenate 'list
                                      (last doc-list)
                                      '("")
                                      (subseq doc-list 0 number-lines)))
          (pruned-subset (if (string-equal (car (last subset)) "")
                             (butlast subset)
                             subset)))
     (mapconcat #'identity pruned-subset "\n"))))
```

Answer (score 4):

I use eldoc, this screenshot shows the first line of `concat`'s docstring:

[image: shoing concat's docstring in eldoc]

```el
(define-advice elisp-get-fnsym-args-string (:around (orig-fun sym &rest r) docstring)
  "If SYM is a function, append its docstring."
  (concat
   (apply orig-fun sym r)
   (let* ((doc (and (fboundp sym) (documentation sym 'raw)))
          (oneline (and doc (substring doc 0 (string-match "\n" doc)))))
     (and oneline
          (stringp oneline)
          (not (string= "" oneline))
          (concat "  |  " (propertize oneline 'face 'italic))))))
```

---

> shown in a temporary popup

You can use tooltip (via the builtin `tooltip-show` or the third party package pos-tip), or overlay (homemade or `popup-tip` from the popup package, or child frame. I believe there also is a package for your purpose (it shows something like Microsoft Clippy alongside?), I can't remember.

Comment: That's a really neat addition to eldoc! `popup-tip` works well in terminal emacs, split on whether I like it or the echo area better.